# Adding dollar amounts when checkbox is not checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add credit amounts when a check box is unchecked and displayed to a div container. I know that there is a `parseFloat()` for decimal integers, but not sure how to use it in this case. I've tried it without decimal integers, but I am not getting anything to display regardless. Any help and clarity would be appreciated. Thank you!

```js
function creditAdd() {
  var credit1 = 0;
  var checkBox1 = document.getElementById("myCheck1");
  if (checkBox1.checked == false){
    var credit1 = 28.48;
  } else {
     var credit1 = 00.00;
  }
  var credit2 = 0;
  var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
  if (checkBox2.checked == false){
      credit2 = 14.24;
  } else {
     var credit2 = 00.00;
  }

  var totalcredit = credit1 + credit2;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totalcredit;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%">
  <input type="checkbox" name="plan-item-1" value="5lb. Ground Chuck" id="myCheck1" onclick="creditAdd()" checked >
  <span>5lb. Ground Chuck</span>
  <span style="display: none; color: #FF0000" id="text1" >
    <strong> $28.45 Credit</strong>
  </span>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%">
   <input type="checkbox" name="plan-item-2" value="3lb. Box SDM Link Sausage" onClick="creditAdd()" id="myCheck2" checked >
   <span>3lb. Box SDM Link Sausage</span> 
   
   <select name="sausage-type" id="selectOne" style="display: inline; margin-bottom: 0px;" required>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="Beef">Beef</option>
      <option value="Pork">Pork</option>
      <option value="Maple Pork">Maple Pork</option>
      <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
   </select>
   
   <span style="display: none; color: #FF0000" id="text2" >
       <strong> $14.24 Credit</strong>
   </span>
</div>

<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: one thing noticeable immediately, you define variable only once, for example you define credit1 3 times. Once you define [ var credit1 ] its done.

Comment: Else part credit1 & credit2 value assignment wrong please make it 0 instead of 00.00 both place And why are you declare var credit1 & credit2 again and again once you declare it'll work. use let keyword instead of var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function creditAdd() {
  var credit1 = 0;
  var checkBox1 = document.getElementById("myCheck1");

  if (checkBox1.checked === false) {
    credit1 = 67.48;
  } else {
    credit1 = 0.00;
  }
  var credit2 = 0;
  var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
  if (checkBox2.checked === false) {
    credit2 = 99.99;
  } else {
    credit2 = 0.00;
  }

  var totalcredit = credit1 + credit2;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totalcredit.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 100%"><input type="checkbox" name="plan-item-1" value="5lb. Ground Chuck" id="myCheck1" onclick="creditAdd()" checked><span>5lb. Ground Chuck</span><span style="display: none; color: #FF0000" id="text1"><strong> $28.45 Credit</strong></span></div>
  <div style="width: 100%"><input type="checkbox" name="plan-item-2" value="3lb. Box SDM Link Sausage" onClick="creditAdd()" id="myCheck2" checked><span>3lb. Box SDM Link Sausage</span>
    <select name="sausage-type" id="selectOne" style="display: inline; margin-bottom: 0px;" required>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="Beef">Beef</option>
      <option value="Pork">Pork</option>
      <option value="Maple Pork">Maple Pork</option>
      <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
    </select><span style="display: none; color: #FF0000" id="text2"><strong> $14.24 Credit</strong></span></div>

  <div id="total"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I fixed the code as suggested and it worked, I've added more credit amounts to the function. Tested it and on one of the credits and it came up with "60.769999999999996". Is there a way to limit it to two decimal points?

Comment: I researched a solution:
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totalcredit.toPrecision(4);

Comment: Thanks everyone for their responses and pointing out my lack of javascript knowledge, It needs work for sure.

Comment: Although my solution will not work if over 99.99. Any thoughts?

Comment: It should work for numbers larger than `99.99`. I've updated the answer to show an example of it doing that.